# form properties not called during resize

Tags: c++, .net, c++-cli

I have a .NET form with a boolean property called `_isResized`, which is set to `true` when the `SizeChanged` event is called and is set to `false` when the `bool isResized()` function is called.

```
ref class net_window : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
private:
    bool _isResized;
public:
    net_window(void)
        : _isResized(false){
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void InitializeComponent(void){
        this->SizeChanged += gcnew EventHandler(this, &net_window::eventResized);
    }

    bool isResized(void){
        bool temp = _isResized;
        _isResized = false;
        return temp;
    }

    Void eventResized(Object^ sender, EventArgs^ e){
        _isResized = true;
    }
};
```

I also have an native C++ class called `window` which acts as a layer around the .NET form. This class is updated every frame of the main loop and uses the `bool isResized()` function of the form to see if the size has changed.

```
class Window
{
private:
    void* _net_window_handle;
    Window(){
        _net_window_handle = new gcroot<net_window^>;
        (*(gcroot<net_window^>*)_net_window_handle) = gcnew net_window;
    }
    ~Window(){
        delete _net_window_handle;
    }

    void update(void)//Called every frame.
    {
        if( (*(gcroot<net_window^>*)_element)->isResized() )
            //Do stuff.
    }
};
```

The delegate added to `SizeChanged` is called whenever the form is being resized, so `_isResized` is set to true as soon as the form size changes, but for some reason the thread of the main loop freezes whenever the window class uses the `bool isResized()` function, until the user has released the edge of the form and thus the resizing has finished.

Is it not possible to access .NET form values as long as it is being resized. Is there an alternative?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I use a main loop which calls `System::Windows::Forms::Application::DoEvents()` every frame. When the thread of the loop enters this function and the main window is resizing, it freezes. Is there a way to avoid this problem.

Comment: If you added some code it would help us to better understand your question.

Comment: DoEvents strikes again.  Windows pumps a modal message loop when the user starts dragging a window edge.  Which means that your DoEvents loop isn't running anymore.  Use a timer instead, SetTimer with a 15 or 31 msec interval is about right.  Having your code respond to the Resize event directly of course highly preferred.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks. If you turn it into a answer, I'll mark it as correct answer.

Comment: I'll pass, I've been beaten up too much before on DoEvent questions. You can post your own answer and mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DoEvents strikes again. Windows pumps a modal message loop when the user starts dragging a window edge. Which means that your DoEvents loop isn't running anymore. Use a timer instead, SetTimer with a 15 or 31 msec interval is about right. Having your code respond to the Resize event directly of course highly preferred.`

Thanks Hans Passant